# Haskell function that works with STUArray

Tags: haskell, state, mutable

I have a small Haskell function that is supposed to accept an `STUArray`, modify some of the elements, and then return the changed array. It will be called from another function working in the `ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)` monad. It part of a fast [`PBKDF2`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) function that I am trying to write. This function does SHA-1 padding for a fixed sized message (160-bits).

Here is my code:

```
padFixed :: STUArray s Int Word32 -> ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
padFixed block = do
  unsafeWrite block 5 0x80000000
  unsafeWrite block 15 160
  return block
```

The array will contain the 20 bytes from a previous SHA-1 run, plus 44 bytes of zeros. It will add the required padding as per [RFC 3174](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174).

How can I rewrite it so is "takes" the array out of the monad, works on it, and then puts it back? The signature should be `padFixed :: ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)`, without the `block` parameter.

Is this possible? I could not find any functions in the library that let me extract the array from the monad, but maybe I missed something.

Are there any good tutorials on the `STArray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible; `ST` doesn't have those semantics.  The monad is `ST s`, and not `ST s (STUArray s a)`.  `ST s` is just a monad for keeping track of mutable state; which structures you choose to allocate and use inside a single `ST` region are up to you.  If you have a bunch of computations which all operate on the same `STUArray`, you can use [`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html):

```
type Hasher s = ReaderT (STUArray s Int Word32) (ST s)

padFixed :: Hasher ()
padFixed = do
  block <- ask
  unsafeWrite block 5  0x80000000
  unsafeWrite block 15 160
```

The `Reader r` monad is just a wrapper around `r ->`; a value of type `Reader r a` is just a function `r -> a`.  This is essentially a way to compute `a` while having access to a value of type `r`.  The `ReaderT r` monad transformer just allows you to provide access to a variable of type `r` to an arbitrary monadic computation; thus, `ReaderT (STUArray s Int Word32) (ST s)` is an `ST s` computation which has access to some array.  Note that you don't need to return the array from `padFixed`; the monad bind will handle all of that.

This'll be a little bit of a pain to write, since we'll have to keep `ask`ing for the array.  Luckily, we can write some combinators to handle this for us:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Word
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST (STUArray, runSTUArray)
import qualified Data.Array.Base as A
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)

newtype Hasher s a =
  Hasher { getHasher :: ReaderT (STUArray s Int Word32) (ST s) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader (A.STUArray s Int Word32))

hasherToST :: Hasher s () -> (Int,Int) -> ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
hasherToST (Hasher r) bounds = do
  block <- A.newArray bounds 0
  runReaderT r block
  return block

runHasher :: (forall s. Hasher s ()) -> (Int,Int) -> UArray Int Word32
runHasher h bounds = runSTUArray $ hasherToST h bounds

-- Perhaps private to this module, perhaps not
liftST :: ST s a -> Hasher s a
liftST = Hasher . lift

----- We can lift the functions which act on an STUArray -----

getBounds :: Hasher s (Int,Int)
getBounds = liftST . A.getBounds =<< ask

-- I'd recommend against removing the `unsafe` from the name; this function
-- could segfault, after all.
unsafeReadBlock :: Int -> Hasher s Word32
unsafeReadBlock i = do
  block <- ask
  liftST $ A.unsafeRead block i

unsafeWriteBlock :: Int -> Word32 -> Hasher s ()
unsafeWriteBlock i x = do
  block <- ask
  liftST $ A.unsafeWrite block i x

----- And then, perhaps in a separate module: -----

padFixed :: Hasher s ()
padFixed = do
  unsafeWriteBlock 5  0x80000000
  unsafeWriteBlock 15 160
```

(Note that I couldn't inline `hasherToST` inside of `runHasher`, probably because of the higher-rank types blocking inference.)

Basically, we wrap the `ReaderT (STUArray s Int Word32) (ST s)` into a `newtype` instead of a type synonym, and lift some basic array primitives up to work on the always-available block.  You don't even need to derive `MonadReader` for the `Hasher` type if you don't want, as long as you lift all the necessary functions.  But once you've done this, your hashing code can talk about the array implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm not sure that using the `ReaderT` monad buys me much over just using the signature that I currently have (maybe aliased with a `type`), but I'll need to reflect on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're confused; that's not possible. Think of `STUArray s i e` as being a pointer to the beginning of a block of memory. You have to pass that pointer around to anything that needs to modify that block of memory; you can't just conjure it up out of thin air.

But you don't need to return it. Presumably the caller already has the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`freeze` and `thaw` functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#g:7) to convert to and from a [`UArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-Unboxed.html#t%3aUArray).

However either this will incur a performance penalty, or you need to use the "unsafe" variants. Since you're already doing unsafe writing, that's probably OK.